# Custom youtube shortcode that uses $content

Tags: shortcode, youtube

I wanna make a simple shortcode that returns the youtube link in a specified size and use the content. Something like:

```
[yt]http://youtu.be/Nl29v5pfxTw[/yt]
```

I have this code, but I want to simplify it:

```
    function youtube($atts) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                "value" => 'http://',
                "width" => '620',
                "height" => '350',
                "name"=> 'movie',
                "allowFullScreen" => 'true',
                "allowScriptAccess"=>'always',
        ), $atts));
        return '<object style="height: '.$height.'px; width: '.$width.'px"><param name="'.$name.'" value="'.$value.'"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="'.$allowFullScreen.'"></param><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="'.$allowScriptAccess.'"></param><embed src="'.$value.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="'.$allowFullScreen.'" allowScriptAccess="'.$allowScriptAccess.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"></embed></object>';
}
add_shortcode("yt", "youtube");
```

The problem is that with this code I need to use [yt value="http://youtu.be/Nl29v5pfxTw"] and I want to just use the [yt]$content[/yt]

How I can achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Shortcode functions accept a [second parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Overview) which contains the value in between the shortcode opening and closing tags:

```
function youtube( $atts, $value = 'http://' ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        "width" => '620',
        "height" => '350',
        "name"=> 'movie',
        "allowFullScreen" => 'true',
        "allowScriptAccess"=>'always',
    ), $atts ) );
    return '<object style="height: '.$height.'px; width: '.$width.'px"><param name="'.$name.'" value="'.$value.'"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="'.$allowFullScreen.'"></param><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="'.$allowScriptAccess.'"></param><embed src="'.$value.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="'.$allowFullScreen.'" allowScriptAccess="'.$allowScriptAccess.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"></embed></object>';
}
add_shortcode( 'yt', 'youtube' );
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function needs to accept a second parameter.

```
function youtube($atts, $content) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                "value" => 'http://',
                "width" => '620',
                "height" => '350',
                "name"=> 'movie',
                "allowFullScreen" => 'true',
                "allowScriptAccess"=>'always',
        ), $atts));
        return '<object style="height: '.$height.'px; width: '.$width.'px"><param name="'.$name.'" value="'.$content.'"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="'.$allowFullScreen.'"></param><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="'.$allowScriptAccess.'"></param><embed src="'.$content.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="'.$allowFullScreen.'" allowScriptAccess="'.$allowScriptAccess.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"></embed></object>';
}
```

I believe that is right. [There are examples in the Codex about how to do this.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: I was first, just ;)

Comment: Yes, you were. Didn't notice until I hit 'submit'. I up-voted you though :)

Comment: For some reason none of these worked.

Comment: @RogerNobrega Please elaborate - what didn't work?

Comment: Hi, sorry fot the delay. It didnt worked, it shows a blank square only